# StrutsTestCase test and "error" returned from Struts2 action class

Tags: java, testing, struts2, struts

I'm trying to use StrutsTestCase for testing my Struts2 actions, but I'm getting always the "error" value back while executing the "execute()" method from the proxy. Here's the example:

> public void testSpike() throws Exception{
>
> ```
>     request.addHeader("param1", "param");
>     
>     ActionProxy proxy = getActionProxy("/action/to/test.action");
>     assertNotNull(proxy);
>
>     TestAction action = (TestAction) proxy.getAction();
>     assertNotNull(action);
>
>     String output = proxy.execute();
> ```
>
> }

the output string is always "error". Is there a way to understand what happened there? The logs are not saying anything, and even trying to debug placing a breakpoint on the Action class doesn't help (the code never stops there).

Any suggestions?

Thanks
Roberto

Answer (score 0):

Add a breakpoint at the line 'String output = proxy.execute();'. Execute your test in debug mode in your favorite IDE and step through the code to realize why execute() method returns always 'error'.